# Python- %s %f %d % etc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I was on this website: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types 
suddenly, at the bottom there are these characters like %f %d %s %.
Does anyone know what it means???

Comment: Here's a link to the explanation on the same website: https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting

Comment: Just a heads up, don't use this notation. `.format()` and f-strings are preferred in Python 3.

Comment: Note that Python also supports a newer style of string formatting that doesn't use `%` via its built-in string [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

Comment: Alright I'll take note of that.

Comment: For reference the % comes from a printf style in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Exercise:

As it says, **%s** (of string) is to replace a string, **%f** (of float) is to replace a float, and **%d** (of integer) is to replace an integer

```
# change this code
mystring = "hello"
myfloat = 10.0
myint = 20

# testing code
if mystring == "hello":
    print("String: %s" % mystring)
if isinstance(myfloat, float) and myfloat == 10.0:
    print("Float: %f" % myfloat)
if isinstance(myint, int) and myint == 20:
    print("Integer: %d" % myint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @A. Gutierrez's answer and provide explanation as to why we do this; In the prior examples (on the site mentioned) we are told that **Python "doesn't support mixing operators between numbers and strings."**

This solution allows you to overcome this.

For example, you would have noticed that:

```
if isinstance(myfloat, float) and myfloat == 10.0:
    print("Float: %f" % myfloat)
```

prints

```
Float: 10.0
```

But using the "+ variable" syntax:

```
if isinstance(myfloat, float) and myfloat == 10.0:
    print("Float: " + myfloat)
```

Would have thrown the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Although with f-string, that doesn't matter as much if you're just parsing as `print(f'value: {myfloat}')`.